# javascript Form submit not working in safari and works in all other browsers?

Tags: javascript, safari

Validation is working fine in all the browsers except Safari. 
It includes 3 sections (a,b,c). In safari A and c section working perfectly. But when I click on B section it shows the alert "enter no of images". My result is `alert('Enter total no. of images');`.

```
function validate()
 {

    if(document.commentform2.rb.value=='wed_custom')
{
    if(document.commentform2.cull_onoffswitch.checked===true)
    {
        if(document.commentform2.cull_images.value=='')
        {

            alert('Enter Cull total images');
            document.commentform2.cull_images.focus();      
            return false;
        }
        if(document.commentform2.cull_max.value=='')
        {
            alert('Enter Maximum no. of images');
            document.commentform2.cull_max.focus();     
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(document.commentform2.str_onoffswitch.checked===false)
    {
        if(document.commentform2.total_images_lr.value=='')
        {
            alert('Enter total no. of images');
            document.commentform2.total_images_lr.focus();      
            return false;
        }
    }

}
else {
 if(document.commentform2.no_images.value=='')
{
    alert('Enter Number of images');
    document.commentform2.no_images.focus();        
    return false;
}
}

return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code 
  `if(document.commentform2.rb.value=='wed_custom')` will always give a `true`

Please replace this line with

```
if(document.getElementById('Id').getAttribute('checked') === 'checked')
```